# Django PDF parser on POST request

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I hope for your help. Because I have been struggling with this problem for a long time. A POST request comes from the frontend with one PDF file, after which I need to take a screenshot of the first page and extract its metadata and save it all in the database.
at the moment I have overridden the POST method and am intercepting the JSON which contains the PDF. I pass this file to my parsing function. But other than the file name, the function cannot find the file. What could be the problem?

view

```
import fitz as fitz
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import FileSerializer


def parce_pdf(test):
    doc = fitz.open(test)  # open document
    pixel = doc[0]  # page pdf
    pix = pixel.get_pixmap()  # render page to an image
    pix.save("media/page.png")  # store image as a PNG
    print(doc.metadata)


class FileView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
        # test = request.data['file'].content_type
        test = request.data['file']
        # print(request.data.get)
        print(test)
        print(request.accepted_media_type)

        parce_pdf(test)
        print(file_serializer)
        # print(test)
        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer

```html
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import File


class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta():
        model = File
        fields = ('file', 'remark', 'timestamp')
```

models

```html
from django.db import models


class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    remark = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

ERROR
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbzBo.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing only the file name from the front end.
It should be either FileObject or Stream.

Try this after changing the front-end code.

```
def parce_pdf(test): # test is a file stream object
    doc = fitz.open('pdf', test)  # open document
    pixel = doc[0]  # page pdf
    pix = pixel.get_pixmap()  # render page to an image
    pix.save("media/page.png")  # store image as a PNG
    print(doc.metadata)


def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
    # test = request.data['file'].content_type
    test = request.FILES['file'] # send file object from front-end
    print(test)
    print(request.accepted_media_type)
    parce_pdf(test)
    print(file_serializer)
    # print(test)
    if file_serializer.is_valid():
        file_serializer.save()
        return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You
*Nanthakumar J J* for your answer. I have just little update in parce_pdf function
as test is a file stream object so it produced error in line `doc = fitz.open('pdf', test)`
The updated funtion is:

```
def parce_pdf(test):
    doc = fitz.open(stream=test.read(), filetype="pdf")  # this line is imporatant
    raw_text = ""
    for page in doc:
        raw_text = raw_text + str(page.getText())
    return raw_text
```

this function is woking very well in my django project.